# XPages Domino Document datasource and documentid : how to trap error?

Tags: xpages

When we declare a dominoDocument as an XPages datasource, we can specify the documentid programmaticaly. However, I've not found a way to trap the error if the specfied id does not exist. I get an error 500 / Could not open document error on the log.

I would expext to get a null "document1" or something but be able to catch error nicely.

```xml
<xp:this.data>
<xp:dominoDocument var="document1" action="openDocument" documentId="some noteId here" formName="Document" ignoreRequestParams="true">
<xp:this.databaseName>...</xp:this.databaseName>
</xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>
```

Any hint ?

thanks

Comment: Just an idea, you can try using queryOpenDocument to check if Document exists and perhaps compute another value for documentId property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the error handling in your code for calculating the documentid.

```xml
<xp:this.documentId><![CDATA[#{javascript: 
    var id = "your calculated id";
    try {
        database.getDocumentByUNID(id);
    } catch(e) {
        context.redirectToPage("pageError", true);
    }
    return id}]]>
</xp:this.documentId>
```

Like in example above you can open e.g. an error page.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I suppose this makes 2 NSF/NIF calls then and it seems a performance killer if I do it on all my custom control :(

Comment: I don't know if it's really an performance killer as both nsf calls are executed on server close to each other and probably it will be used some internal caching.

Comment: `getDocumentByUNID` is extremely fast... excessive index access is typically what causes most Domino apps to be slow. If memory serves, though, `getDocumentByUNID` throws an error if the ID is invalid, so instead of checking for `null` you'd have to wrap it in a `try` and move `redirectToPage` to the corresponding `catch`.